R webscraping for specific value, seems to be outside of table
I want to obtain the value 6.911,930 from the following website:
https://www2.bmf.com.br/pages/portal/bmfbovespa/boletim1/SistemaPregao1.asp?pagetype=pop&caminho=Resumo%20Estat%EDstico%20-%20Sistema%20Preg%E3o&Data=04/06/2024&Mercadoria=DAP
I have tried to transform it into a table using the following code:
link <- "https://www2.bmf.com.br/pages/portal/bmfbovespa/boletim1/SistemaPregao1.asp?pagetype=pop&caminho=Resumo%20Estat%EDstico%20-%20Sistema%20Preg%E3o&Data=04/06/2024&Mercadoria=DAP"

Pag_bmf <- read_html(link)
table_node = html_nodes(Pag_bmf ,"table")
table_content <- html_table(table_node)[[5]] 

I am new to webscraping, and as far as I can tell the value I want is in the following line
/html/body/div/div[2]/form[1]/table[5]/tbody/tr[3]/td


There's active javascript, so rendered page structure that you see in inspector of your browser's dev.tools is not quite the same as you'd get through rvest::read_html(). Even if you do disable javascript in your browsers first, browser can still change DOM tree, so selector or xpath copied from dev.tools might not work with rvest; in this case
browser is adding <tbody> ( Why do browsers insert tbody element into table elements? ). When you remove that added tbody from your included xpath, it should then work with html_elements().
And then there are nested tables, figuring out correct index in the list of parsed tables by just looking at the selector / xpath can get bit tricky (form[1]/table[5] is not the same as html_table(table_node)[[5]] ).
If the the string is constant, you can just search for that <td></td> element containing (parts of) it:
library(rvest)
link <- "https://www2.bmf.com.br/pages/portal/bmfbovespa/boletim1/SistemaPregao1.asp?pagetype=pop&caminho=Resumo%20Estat%EDstico%20-%20Sistema%20Preg%E3o&Data=04/06/2024&Mercadoria=DAP"
html <- read_html(link) 

html |> 
  html_element(xpath = '//td[contains(text(),"INDICE IPCA")]') |>
  html_text()
#> [1] "VALOR INDICE IPCA PRO RATA TEMPORE: 6.911,930"

If position seems to be more stable than string value, then you could get 3rd row of the last table in form with something like this:
html |> 
  html_elements("form > table:last-child > tr:nth-of-type(3)") |> 
  # or xpath = "//form/table[last()]/tr[3]
  html_text(trim = TRUE)
#> [1] "VALOR INDICE IPCA PRO RATA TEMPORE: 6.911,930"

Created on 2024-06-05 with reprex v2.1.0
